# Symfony 3.3: Use php file inside bundle to load routes expects class

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-routing

To my Symfony version 3.3 project at `app/config/routing.yml` file I have put:

```yaml
AppBundle:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.php'
    prefix: /
    type: 'php'
```

And on `src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.php` I have put the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('blog_list', new Route('/blog', array(
    '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Blog:list',
)));
$collection->add('blog_show', new Route('/blog/{slug}', array(
    '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Blog:show',
)));

return $collection;
```

But I get the following error:

> The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Resources\config\routing" to be defined in file "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/myblog/vendor/composer/../../src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/myblog/app/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/myblog/app/config/config.yml").

Do you know fellows how to load the routes via a "external" php file? I mean in the very same way you load via yml the routes to load them via php.

As fas as I know according to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html you can use php file to load the routes.

Comment: Symfony version?  What you have looks like it should work.

Comment: It says on the title

Comment: I forgot I answered this already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099282/symfony-using-yaml-and-php-routing/46100447#46100447

Answer (score -1):

May be its because you don't have a namespace in your routing.php file.

You have to put at the beginning of the file :

```
namespace AppBundle\Resources\config;
```

Comment: Nope still asks for a class.

Comment: Maybe you can only configure php routes like that in the default file (app/config/routing.yml|php) and the only solution to add others routes in php is to create a [custom route loader](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html)

Comment: @FabienSalles - At the risk of being harsh, maybe you should stop guessing and start reading the docs and do a bit of testing.

Comment: The docs only have examples for the file `app/config/routing.*` configure in the config.yml. So it's fine. I already read it !